# Shell script to open files in browser not working as expected

Tags: macos, shell

I have 70 folders that each correspond to a webpage that I want to open using one single script. I quickly wrote this:

```
i=0
for entry in *
do
    i=$((i+1))
    /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "http://localhost:9905/?template=$entry&data=$entry"
done
echo "$i"
```

However, while `i` ends up equalling 70, it seems like only about 20 of the webpages are actually opening in chrome. Does my mac limit how many pages can be opened in a given time or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems like using it with safari instead of chrome works better

Comment: Did you try adding a short delay?